# Guerrilla usability testing

Tags: user-behavior, usability-testing, users, testing, guerrilla-user-research

I want to do a guerrilla usability testing and I was wondering if it is ok to ask to the participant to draw/sketch his thoughts as well?

Comment: Tester = the person giving the test. Why is this individual  drawing *during* the test, instead of being prepared. Guerrilla testing still has clear structure and goals, the environment and participants is just less formal.

Comment: Sorry I mean the participant not the tester.

Answer (score 2):

## Make the participant feel comfortable

Ask the user to do whatever they feel comfortable with to clarify an idea. Some people are going to freeze when you ask them to draw anything. Others will grab your pen and a napkin at the first opportunity to avoid fumbling with words.

Unless you are doing it with a very precise psychological goal in mind, you don't want to take a participant too far out of their comfort zone. They will clam up and stop thinking and communicating clearly. That won't do you or them any good.

Comment: I strongly concur with this answer. Guerilla testing allows the tester some flexibility in their feedback. Restricting them to drawing a picture is no better than restricting them to multiple choice, the medium of dance, or any other form of art. The key is to put the focus on the results of the test rather than the structure of the communication